# Syntax error creating table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting a syntax error when I'm trying to create the table in MySQL database, it is around the MEDIUMBLOB, can anyone help me?

```html
CREATE TABLE  `ELO`.`images` (

 `image_id` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `user_id` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `image` MEDIUMBLOB(16777215) NOT NULL ,
 `longitude` VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
 `latitude` VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
 `city` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `delete_at` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 `description` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
 `score` INT( 8 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `categories` SET(  'nightlife',  'food',  'beach' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'nightlife',
PRIMARY KEY (  `image_id` ) ,
UNIQUE (
 `image`
)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set length for `MEDIUMBLOB` the column should be defined just   `image MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,` which means you can't set it also as `UNIQUE` as it don't have length so your sql should look like this

```
CREATE TABLE  `images` (
 `image_id` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `user_id` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `image` MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
 `longitude` VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
 `latitude` VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
 `city` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `delete_at` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 `description` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
 `score` INT( 8 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `categories` SET(  'nightlife',  'food',  'beach' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'nightlife',
 PRIMARY KEY (  `image_id` ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```